# How to add a n-mosfet subckt model in gschem ngspice?

Tags: model, ngspice

I want to add a N-Mosfet subckt Model.

```
.SUBCKT ZVN0124A 3 4 5
*                D G S
M1 3 2 5 5 MN0124
RG 4 2 225
RL 3 5 2.4E7
C1 2 5 60E-12
C2 3 2 2E-12 
D1 5 3 DN0124
*
.MODEL MN0124 NMOS VTO=1.5512 RS=1.436 RD=9.254 IS=1E-15 KP=1.077
+CBD=36E-12 PB=1 LAMBDA=0
.MODEL DN0124 D IS=3.071E-12 N=1.026 RS=0.511
.ENDS ZVN0124A
```

What have I do:

This are the attributes of spice-model-1.sym
[image]

This are the attributes of Mosfet
[image]

If I start the simulation I get a error:

```
**gnetlist -g spice-sdb -o buck1.net buck1.sch**
**ngspice** 
*ngspice 2 ->* **source buck1.net**

Error on line 44 : mq1 ub us2 um zvn0540a
  Unable to find definition of model  - default assumed
```

Answer (score 1):

What happens when you generate the netlist if you use `device=NMOS_TRANSISTOR` is gnetlist assumes it's looking for a MODEL definition even though you are loading a SUBCKT. gnetlist will then "correct" `refdes=Q1` to `MQ1` and fail to find the model. In fact, even if you explicitly make `refdes=X1` it will change it to `MX1`.

The solution is instead to use **`device=SUBCKT_NMOS`** and **`refdes=X1`** and you will find gnetlist leaves it alone.

[Re: [Ngspice-users] Adding attributes to subcircuit that show up in netlist](https://sourceforge.net/p/ngspice/mailman/message/31999881/)

> This has been *quietly* included since 2011 and is present in the gaf
>   1.8 stable release.

Emphasis added ;)

Answer (score 0):

I think the refdes of the FET needs to be "X?". (Or Check netlist and change Q to X). Otherwise, ngspice doesn't recognise it as a model with an external definition.